# Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@ee48bb3 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

There are related questions but not totally similar for which I was looking for hence publishing this problem
**Description**: This warning(SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)) comes intermittently and immedietly after this there is exception in springboot java code while fetching(select query) record from the database where it uses springboot jparepository concept.

Below is the exception trace of WARN

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection:::ProxyConnection.java:::checkException:::182:::HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@ee48bb3 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 949,021 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 949,022 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setReadOnlyInternal(ConnectionImpl.java:2161)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2145)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setReadOnly(ProxyConnection.java:423)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setReadOnly(HikariProxyConnection.ja
```

immedietly after above WARN, service code is failing due to below exception where springboot jparepository is used

```
:::D3931305D3A84D82AACF29594A0432C8::::::Monitor:::com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask:::ProxyLeakTask.java:::cancel:::91:::Previously reported leaked connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@ee48bb3 on thread http-nio-9090-exec-69 was returned to the pool (unleaked)
2021-09-07 **21:39:52,100:::ERROR:::D3931305D3A84D82AACF29594A0432C8:::saveRunConfigurations:::388:::Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:**
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:448)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
.
.
```

Below are the HikariCp Configurations and values of timeout of mysql db

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=150
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=900000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1000000
spring.datasource.hikari.validationTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold=90000

---

 MySQL [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "%wait%";
+---------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------------------------------------------+----------+
| innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold | 600 |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50 |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay | 6 |
| lock_wait_timeout | 31536000 |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size | 10000 |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_size | 10 |
| shutdown_wait_connection_timeout | 500 |
| thread_pool_batch_wait_timeout | 10000 |
| wait_timeout | 180 |


MySQL [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%timeout%";
+----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+----------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout | 10 |
| delayed_insert_timeout | 300 |
| have_statement_timeout | YES |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1 |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50 |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF |
| interactive_timeout | 28800 |
| lock_wait_timeout | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout | 120 |
| net_write_timeout | 240 |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout | 31536000 |
| shutdown_wait_connection_timeout | 500 |
| slave_net_timeout | 60 |
| tcp_linger_timeout | 10 |
| thread_pool_batch_wait_timeout | 10000 |\
| wait_timeout | 28800 |
```

As the issue was on PROD env so I have to reproduce the issue on Lower env to find the exact RCA
hence

1. tried with same configurations but still it did not reproduce on Lower env
2. At firts I thought it is due to lower value of wait_timeout hence tried with increasing wait_timeout to 28800 still did not reproduce
3. tried with increasing load on Mysql in Lower env
4. It may be due to firewall restrictions or something but I am not getting it exactly what to check
5. tried with decreasing the value of spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=100000

It would be greate help for suggestions on finding the exact cause of this problem and how to reproduce this issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some kind of idle connection timeout configured on the server. You should be able to get around that by configuring your connection pool to do connection validation queries every X seconds. Look into the documentation, it looks like `keepaliveTime` is the setting that you should set to e.g. 300000 (5 minutes in ms): https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP